# Comparing SplFileInfo objects always returns true

Tags: php

I've pretty much convinced myself that this is just leaky abstraction rearing it's ugly head, but I figured before filing a bug report I might probe Stack Overflow for a more insightful answer...

I'm writing a class in PHP to assist autoloading. I hate using the ridiculous, path-oriented class names like the Zend framework uses, so I've instead written a class that creates an object to recursively go through a directory and its subdirectories, find all PHP source files, and parse them for class definitions, which are then cached and reused until an autoload fails, which prompts the object to update its index.

I like to use built-in PHP classes wherever possible, so for the indexed paths I've used the `SplFileInfo` class.

Some of the operations required to update the index of classes require that I search the array of `SplFileInfo` objects my object holds, which is where I have run into a little trouble with using the comparison operator on the `SplFileInfo` object.

Simply put, searching for any file always returns true. I was a little baffled by it at first, but I've tried it on two machines and had a friend try it on his--same result. Seemingly no matter what, when you compare two `SplFileInfo` objects using the comparison (`==`) operator, it returns true, even if they point to different files located in completely directories. Whether I use a loop to iterate over each element in the array and compare that way, use `in_array()`, or `array_search()`, it always returns true and gives me a reference to a completely different file.

I poked around a little further and found that the identify operator (`===`) always returns false, even when two `SplFileInfo` objects point to exactly the same file, initialized with the same path string.

For my code, this means that when I go to update the class index to see if there are any new files, even if a file is new, the indexer object thinks it already knows about that file and moves on. I've made this to work by comparing the pathname strings, but that sort of defeats the purpose of using the `SplFileInfo` class to begin with.

The PHP manual says that extension developers can overload the comparison operators for objects, which is why I sort of assumed that `SplFileInfo` was smart enough to resolve relative paths and properly compare it with other relative paths, e.g. `./file` and `file` are equal. Turns out, it was only returning true in those instances because it *always* returns true when comparing two `SplFileInfo` objects!

This isn't linked to the code I'm working on. I tried a scratch source file with some new `SplFileInfo` objects, and compared them. It returns true whether the objects point to different files, the same file, and files that don't exist.

Since this isn't the default behavior for comparison operators on objects in PHP, there has to be something in the definition of the class in the extension that is causing this.

Does anyone have any idea why it's behaving like this, or have any insight?

Comment: +1, although I question your autoloading approach, I find the question intriguing nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah I imagine most people would. But this is almost identical to how symfony autoloads its core classes.

Comment: BTW: the strict comparison operator `===` behaviour you mention is simply expected behaviour, because, although they internally may hold the same data, the objects themself are not references to the same object. They are distinct instances.

Comment: BTW 2: can you point me to the manual about the comparison operator overloading. I can't seem to find it, but be much interested in reading it.

Comment: http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php It's in the table about comparing different types.

Comment: @fireeyedboy: I know I am question-necromancing, but I stumbled upon this question in a similar persut and was wandering why you raised objections to the autoloading approach?

Comment: @DudeOnRock To be honest; I'm not entirely sure anymore why I objected to this approach. I think it probably was because I value pseudo-namespaces over having no namespaces at all. But that is not necessarily related to the autoloading. Perhaps I overlooked the cache part that Andrew was talking about, the first time around, and thus concluded that lazy-loading / loading-on-demand would be more efficient.

Comment: @DudeOnRock Or... not knowing the exact caching implementation; if an existing class is modified, the caching mechanism must have some way of knowing this. And I can't think of a mechanism that doesn't involve having to iterate all files each time to check this, of the top of my head. Making this a possibly very inefficient approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrew,

I've done some experimenting myself with the [SPL](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/) classes, and surpisingly SplFileInfo is not the only SPL class that exhibits this behaviour. ArrayIterator, for instance, reacts the same way too. I presume more (if not all) SPL classes have this behaviour.

Although I don't have an answer as to why this behaviour exists, I do have a workaround for your specific case. You may have come up with this yourself already, but I thought I'ld share it anyway:

```
class MyFileInfo extends SplFileInfo
{
    private $_realPath;

    public function __construct( $path )
    {
        parent::__construct( $path );
        $this->_realPath = $this->getRealPath();
    }

}
```

Comment: Yep, that was how I solved it (rather than comparing the actual pathnames of the object, which could differ for the same file). `$file1->getRealPath() === $file2->getRealPath();`

Comment: I'm just gonna go ahead and accept this as an answer since nobody else is saying anything.