# Why can't SplFileInfo be converted to boolean?

Tags: php, spl, truthiness

One of the limitations of PHP is that objects always evaluate to `true`. However `SplFileinfo` (and subclasses such as Symfony's `UploadedFile`) behave differently:

```
$a = new ArrayIterator();       // or any other class
$b = new SplFileInfo(__FILE__); // file used is not important

if ($a) echo 'true';   // 'true'
if (!$a) echo 'false'; // nothing because $a is true

if ($b) echo 'true';   // 'true'
if (!$b) echo 'false'; // Catchable fatal error: Object of class 
                       // SplFileInfo could not be converted to boolean
```

Is this a bug? Tested in 5.3 and 5.4. Also happens with `SplFileObject`. Possible [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130372/comparing-splfileinfo-objects-always-returns-true). And [a Symfony issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/536) from 2011.

Answer (score 7):

I feel it's a bug so I filed a bug report.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65213

-- Edit, somewhere roughly around php 5.6.17 this bug seems to have been fixed.

Comment: And someone else thinks it's a feature ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I came across this issue as well. I don't know what PHP's rational for this exception is.

For anyone else coming across this, an easy workaround is just to compare the SplFileInfo object to false.

```
$b = new SplFileInfo(__FILE__);
if ($b != false) {
   echo "This will not throw an exception";
}

if (!$b) {
   echo "This will throw an exception";
}
```